# I Cleaned all projects, now when I try to run I get Error: Could not find or load main class?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, boilerpipe

I wanted to use boilerpipe so I added all .jars to the build path for my project. I did

```
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.DefaultExtractor;
```

and in one of my methods

```
return(DefaultExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(someURL);
```

Eclipse is telling me that the import cannot be resolved even though I see DefaultExtractor.java under 'Referenced Libraries'. Someone suggested I clean all of my projects. I did, and now when I try to run I get an error saying:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class XXXX
```

How do I make it so I am able to run my code again? And once I do, how can I get boilerpipe to work? Thank you.

Comment: Does it really say XXXX or does it say something else in place of the XXXX?

Comment: It says the class name from which I try to run. In this case "TradeSimulator". If I try to run from the other class in the project, it says that name instead. @RobertHarvey

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the project configuration, if the class is in the right package, has the right visibility and so on. You say you see .java, does that mean its  not compiled?

Comment: boilerpipe wasn't properly compiling properly. It threw a monkey wrench in the whole project. I'm yet to implement it properly, but I deleted it to see if that was the problem, sure enough it was.